# libkcapi - Error: Netlink error: cannot open netlink socket

Tags: socket, random

I am trying to play with my random generator, so I decided to give [libkcapi](http://www.chronox.de/libkcapi/html/index.html) a try.

Here is what I did:

```
$ wget http://www.chronox.de/libkcapi/libkcapi-0.13.0.tar.xz
$ tar xf libkcapi-0.13.0.tar.xz
$ cd libkcapi-0.13.0
$ cd lib
$ make
$ cd ../test
$ make
$ ./kcapi -x 3  -c sha1  -p 8c899bba
libkcapi - Error: Netlink error: cannot open netlink socket
libkcapi - Error: Netlink error: cannot open netlink socket
libkcapi - Error: NETLINK_CRYPTO: cannot obtain cipher information for sha1 (is required crypto_user.c patch missing? see documentation)
Allocation of hash sha1 failed
Failed to invoke testing
```

Taking a look at strace output here is what I see:

```
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_CRYPTO) = -1 EPROTONOSUPPORT (Protocol not supported)
write(2, "libkcapi - Error: Netlink error:"..., 60libkcapi - Error: Netlink error: cannot open netlink socket
) = 60
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_CRYPTO) = -1 EPROTONOSUPPORT (Protocol not supported)
write(2, "libkcapi - Error: Netlink error:"..., 60libkcapi - Error: Netlink error: cannot open netlink socket
) = 60
write(2, "libkcapi - Error: NETLINK_CRYPTO"..., 137libkcapi - Error: NETLINK_CRYPTO: cannot obtain cipher information for sha1 (is required crypto_user.c patch missing? see documentation)
```

As mentionned in the toplevel README.md file:

> The kernel interface and therefore this library can be used by
>   unprivileged processes.

I also tried using `sudo` without much luck.

For reference I am using:

```
$ uname -a
Linux macbookpro 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Does anyone knows how to use the `libkcapi` on Linux ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the answer was pretty easy. From the documentation:

- http://www.chronox.de/libkcapi/html/ch02s08.html#idm140613609406960

I need the following:

- CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER
- CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API
- CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_HASH
- CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_SKCIPHER
- CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_AEAD
- CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_RNG
- (CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_AKCIPHER) not required

However here is what I get with the default Debian kernel:

```
% grep CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER /boot/config-4.9.0-3-amd64 
# CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER is not set
CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_HASH=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_SKCIPHER=m
# CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_RNG is not set
CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_AEAD=m
```

I reported it, let's see what happen:

- https://bugs.debian.org/868291